# Elastic Search- Distinct elements from multiple fields

Tags: elasticsearch

I created a mapping to index my `mongoDb` collection using elastic search. Here is the `mapping` properties:

```
"properties" : {
          "address_components" : {
            "properties" : {
              "_id" : {
                "type" : "string"
              },
              "subLocality1" : {
                "type" : "string",
                "index" : "not_analyzed"
              },
              "subLocality2" : {
                "type" : "string",
                "index" : "not_analyzed"
              },
              "subLocality3" : {
                "type" : "string",
                "index" : "not_analyzed"
              }, 
             "city" : {
                "type" : "string",
                "index" : "not_analyzed"
              }
            }
```

Now, I want to retrieve overall unique items from these fields: `subLocality1`, `subLocality2`, `subLocality3`, `city`. 
Also, each of the `distinct` value should contain `q` as a sub-string. 
Distinct item should also contain corresponding `city` value.

Example:

```
"address_components" : {
    "subLocality1" : "s1"
    "subLocality2" : "s1",
    "subLocality3" : "s2",
    "city":"a"
  }

"address_components" : {
    "subLocality1" : "s3"
    "subLocality2" : "s1",
    "subLocality3" : "s2",
    "city":"a"
  }

"address_components" : {
    "subLocality1" : "s2"
    "subLocality2" : "s1",
    "subLocality3" : "s4",
    "city":"a"
  }
```

For above indexes,
the expected result is:

```
"address_components" : {
    "subLocality1" : "s1"
    "subLocality2" : "s1",
    "subLocality3" : "s2",
    "city":"ct1"
  }

"address_components" : {
    "subLocality1" : "s3"
    "subLocality2" : "s1",
    "subLocality3" : "s2",
    "city":"ct1"
  }

"address_components" : {
    "subLocality1" : "s2"
    "subLocality2" : "s1",
    "subLocality3" : "s4",
    "city":"ct1"
  }
{s1, a}, {s2,a}, {s3,a}, {s4,a},{a,a}
```

I tried doing it using elastic search `terms` aggregation.

```
GET /rescu/rescu/_search?pretty=true&search_type=count

{
    "aggs" : {
        "distinct_locations" : {
            "terms" : {
                "script" : "doc['address_components.subLocality1'].value"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But `terms` aggregations only applies for single field according to following [link](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_multi_field_terms_aggregation).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the answer myself, after going through elastic search api docs.
We need to use a script to retrieve terms from multiple fields.

```
GET /rescu/rescu/_search?pretty=true&search_type=count
{
  "aggs": {
    "distinct_locations": {
      "terms": {
        "script": "[doc['address_components.subLocality1'].value,doc['address_components.subLocality2'].value,doc['address_components.subLocality3'].value]",
        "size": 5000
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This has the issue of not returning field names. 
"buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "[1400 W WILSON ST]",
          "doc_count" : 18
        },
        {
          "key" : "[79007]",
          "doc_count" : 18
        },
        {
          "key" : "[BORGER]",
          "doc_count" : 18
        },
        {
          "key" : "[TX]",
          "doc_count" : 18
        }
      ]

Answer (score 5):

Here is example with two fields: Country, City. It uses Aggregations by Country, and Sub-Aggregations by City:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "country": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "country"
      },
      "aggregations": {
        "city": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "city"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can use many layers of sub-aggregations.

Answer (score 4):

If you use the query provided by Fuad Efendi:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "country": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "country"
      },
      "aggregations": {
        "city": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "city"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It is important to note that **the first aggregation will be scoped to any "query" you add, but the second aggregation on "city" will not and will instead be scoped to the entire database.** This might not be what you want.

Personally, I find the answer provided by ritesh_NITW using a script, to have the best result.

Answer (score 2):

I came here from Google searching how to do this in a Kibana visualization.

Looks like [Ritesh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1348550/ritesh-kumar-gupta)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28115097/elastic-search-distinct-elements-from-multiple-fields/28117691#28117691) is very helpful there as well.

I wanted to do a Unique Count aggregation on two fields: `IPAddress` and `Message`.

In Kibana Visualizations, the `JSON Input` field

[image: JSON Input field in Kibana Visualizations]

helps you to modify the aggregation part of the query sent to ElasticSearch.

However, you have to extract stuff from Ritesh's answer. It's only the `script` part that you need.

In my case:

```
{
    "script": "[doc['extra.IPAddress'].value,doc['extra.Message'].value]"
}
```

Now, what is really missing here in the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.6/search-aggregations-metrics-cardinality-aggregation.html) is that the `script` parameter takes precedence over the `field` parameter. This is what happens in Kibana. The `field` parameter is sent from the interface, and the `script` parameter is sent because you added it in the `JSON input` textbox.